Isserli's formula for sinus of Gaussians r.v.s.
Let $n$ be an integer, $(N_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ is a Gaussian vector with zero mean and covariances $\mathbb{E}[N_i N_j] = c_{i, j}$. I would like to obtain a formula for
$$f_n = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\sin(N_i)\right],$$
which is similar to the Isserlis theorem, concerning $ \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{n} N_i\right]$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem). More precisely, I would like to obtain a quantitative version of
$$f_n \simeq \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{n} N_i\right],$$
when $c_{i, i} \to 0$.
I suspect that this kind of expectation appears somewhere in the litterature, but I wasn't able to find it. Someone told me that this kind of expectation could appear in random matrix theory.
My progress so far are the following. Let $E$ be a Rademacher random variable. Expressing $\sin(N_i) = \mathbb{E}\left[E e^{i E N_i}|N_i \right]$, one can linearize the product to get:
$$f_n = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^n E_i \exp(-\frac12 \sum_{i, j} c_{i,j} E_i E_j)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^n E_i \prod_{i, j}  \exp(-\frac12 c_{i,j} E_i E_j)\right],$$
where $(E_i)$ are i.i.d. Rademacher.
Then, using $e^{x \epsilon} = \cosh(x)+\epsilon \sinh(x)$ for $\epsilon \in \{-1, 1\}$, one can expand the product again and obtain
$$f_n = \sum_{P} (-1)^{\#P} \prod_{(i,j) \in P^c} \cosh(c_{i,j}) \prod_{(i, j) \in P} \sinh(c_{i,j}),$$
where the sum runs over the subset of $\{(i, j)\}$ such that all the indexes of $\{1, .., n\}$ appears an odd number of times in these subsets. The issue with this formula, is that the sums runs over many subsets (of order $2^{n^2}$). Cancellations are provided by the factor $(-1)^{\#P}$, but I my problem I have to upper bound $|f_n|$, so this formula seems hardly manageable. Moreover, if we upper bound the $(-1)^{\#P}$ factor by $1$, one can do the computation in the reverse way to notice that we in fact upper bounded $|f_n|$ by $\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\sinh(N_i)\right]$, which is way too large.
I also try to use the integration by parts formula for Gaussian vector, but without sucess.
Edit: I suspect that one can apply Theorem 1 of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.00189. Since one can write $\sin(x) = x \operatorname{sinc}(x)$, and use this (quite technical) integration by part formula.
